# error in new version of sails and mongodb when want to insert data to table

Tags: sails.js

Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at Object.createUser [as user/createuser] (E:\angular2\server-sails\test\api\controllers\UserController.js:13:5)
datasrore.js

```
   /**
 * Datastores
 * (sails.config.datastores)
 *
 * A set of datastore configurations which tell Sails where to fetch or save
 * data when you execute built-in model methods like `.find()` and `.create()`.
 *
 *  > This file is mainly useful for configuring your development database,
 *  > as well as any additional one-off databases used by individual models.
 *  > Ready to go live?  Head towards `config/env/production.js`.
 *
 * For more information on configuring datastores, check out:
 * https://sailsjs.com/config/datastores
 */

module.exports.datastores = {


  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Your app's default datastore.                                            *
  *                                                                          *
  * Sails apps read and write to local disk by default, using a built-in     *
  * database adapter called `sails-disk`.  This feature is purely for        *
  * convenience during development; since `sails-disk` is not designed for   *
  * use in a production environment.                                         *
  *                                                                          *
  * To use a different db _in development_, follow the directions below.     *
  * Otherwise, just leave the default datastore as-is, with no `adapter`.    *
  *                                                                          *
  * (For production configuration, see `config/env/production.js`.)          *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  default: {

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Want to use a different database during development?                     *
    *                                                                          *
    * 1. Choose an adapter:                                                    *
    *    https://sailsjs.com/plugins/databases                                 *
    *                                                                          *
    * 2. Install it as a dependency of your Sails app.                         *
    *    (For example:  npm install sails-mysql --save)                        *
    *                                                                          *
    * 3. Then pass it in, along with a connection URL.                         *
    *    (See https://sailsjs.com/config/datastores for help.)                 *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/
    // adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    // url: 'mysql://user:password@host:port/database',
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/server',

  },


};
```

model.js:

````
/**
 * Default model settings
 * (sails.config.models)
 *
 * Your default, project-wide model settings. Can also be overridden on a
 * per-model basis by setting a top-level properties in the model definition.
 *
 * For details about all available model settings, see:
 * https://sailsjs.com/config/models
 *
 * For more general background on Sails model settings, and how to configure
 * them on a project-wide or per-model basis, see:
 * https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings
 */

module.exports.models = {


  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Whether the `.create()` and `.update()` model methods should ignore      *
  * (and refuse to persist) unrecognized data-- i.e. properties other than   *
  * those explicitly defined by attributes in the model definition.          *
  *                                                                          *
  * To ease future maintenance of your code base, it is usually a good idea  *
  * to set this to `true`.                                                   *
  *                                                                          *
  * > Note that `schema: false` is not supported by every database.          *
  * > For example, if you are using a SQL database, then relevant models     *
  * > are always effectively `schema: true`.  And if no `schema` setting is  *
  * > provided whatsoever, the behavior is left up to the database adapter.  *
  * >                                                                        *
  * > For more info, see:                                                    *
  * > https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/orm/model-settings#?schema           *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  // schema: true,


  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * How and whether Sails will attempt to automatically rebuild the          *
  * tables/collections/etc. in your schema.                                  *
  *                                                                          *
  * > Note that, when running in a production environment, this will be      *
  * > automatically set to `migrate: 'safe'`, no matter what you configure   *
  * > here.  This is a failsafe to prevent Sails from accidentally running   *
  * > auto-migrations on your production database.                           *
  * >                                                                        *
  * > For more info, see:                                                    *
  * > https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/orm/model-settings#?migrate          *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  migrate: 'alter',


  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Base attributes that are included in all of your models by default.      *
  * By convention, this is your primary key attribute (`id`), as well as two *
  * other timestamp attributes for tracking when records were last created   *
  * or updated.                                                              *
  *                                                                          *
  * > For more info, see:                                                    *
  * > https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/orm/model-settings#?attributes       *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    // id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true, },
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  /\   Using MongoDB?
    //  ||   Replace `id` above with this instead:
    //
    // ```
    id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' },
    // ```
    //
    // Plus, don't forget to configure MongoDB as your default datastore:
    // https://sailsjs.com/docs/tutorials/using-mongo-db
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  },


  /******************************************************************************
  *                                                                             *
  * The set of DEKs (data encryption keys) for at-rest encryption.              *
  * i.e. when encrypting/decrypting data for attributes with `encrypt: true`.   *
  *                                                                             *
  * > The `default` DEK is used for all new encryptions, but multiple DEKs      *
  * > can be configured to allow for key rotation.  In production, be sure to   *
  * > manage these keys like you would any other sensitive credential.          *
  *                                                                             *
  * > For more info, see:                                                       *
  * > https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/orm/model-settings#?dataEncryptionKeys  *
  *                                                                             *
  ******************************************************************************/

  dataEncryptionKeys: {
    default: '3X6yTfIErxEHDahmUxEdiRFg8rR8eU0/H8Z2AiGnNmU='
  },


  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Whether or not implicit records for associations should be cleaned up    *
  * automatically using the built-in polyfill.  This is especially useful    *
  * during development with sails-disk.                                      *
  *                                                                          *
  * Depending on which databases you're using, you may want to disable this  *
  * polyfill in your production environment.                                 *
  *                                                                          *
  * (For production configuration, see `config/env/production.js`.)          *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  cascadeOnDestroy: true


};
````

userController.js

```
module.exports = {

  createUser: (req, res) => {
    var params = req.allParams();
    console.log('hello world')
    user.create({name: 'samira'}).exec((err, userCreated) => {
        res.ok('userCreated');
    })
  }

};
```

user.js

```
/**
 * User.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    }
    //  ╔═╗╦═╗╦╔╦╗╦╔╦╗╦╦  ╦╔═╗╔═╗
    //  ╠═╝╠╦╝║║║║║ ║ ║╚╗╔╝║╣ ╚═╗
    //  ╩  ╩╚═╩╩ ╩╩ ╩ ╩ ╚╝ ╚═╝╚═╝


    //  ╔═╗╔╦╗╔╗ ╔═╗╔╦╗╔═╗
    //  ║╣ ║║║╠╩╗║╣  ║║╚═╗
    //  ╚═╝╩ ╩╚═╝╚═╝═╩╝╚═╝


    //  ╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╦╔═╗╔╦╗╦╔═╗╔╗╔╔═╗
    //  ╠═╣╚═╗╚═╗║ ║║  ║╠═╣ ║ ║║ ║║║║╚═╗
    //  ╩ ╩╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝╩╩ ╩ ╩ ╩╚═╝╝╚╝╚═╝

  },

};
```

how can i solve this error and im beginner in sails, thank you advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalise `User`...

```
User.create({name: 'samir...
```